# How can I push a rep to github with an unrelated histories in Visual Studio and Github Desktop?

Tags: git, github

While I was trying to push a my Code to Github I got this Error message:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How can i still push it to github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

`$ git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`

before pushing again and it should works.